# Unclosed batch after opened WhatsApp desktop program in batch file

Tags: batch

I run a batch file to open the microsoft edge as well as WhatsApp desktop version after both programs are launched, the batch itself does not close. Please advise what should be rectified. Thanks

```
@echo off
microsoftedge.exe
"C:\Program 
Files\WindowsApps\5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_2.2332.9.0_x64__cv1g1gvanyjgm\WhatsApp.exe"

:end
@exit /b
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When called like that, the script is basically sitting there waiting for those applications to finish/close before continuing with the script.

You need to call them using the `start` command, which will call each app and then return control to the script so it can continue and then depending on how it's called, either return you to the cmd prompt (if run from an open cmd prompt), or close the window (if the .bat is run from Windows).

```
@echo off
start microsoftedge.exe
start "C:\Program 
Files\WindowsApps\5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_2.2332.9.0_x64__cv1g1gvanyjgm\WhatsApp.exe"

:end
@exit /b
```

Comment: Check the syntax for `start` - the first item in quotes is the window title so you need to start with `start "" ...` (pun intended). See [Start - Start a program - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off

start "" /b "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\MicrosoftEdge.exe"
start "" /b "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\5319275A.WhatsAppDesktop_2.2332.9.0_x64__cv1g1gvanyjgm\WhatsApp.exe"
```

---

Use: `Start "" /B`

```
Syntax
START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
​
Key:
title       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
path        Starting directory.
command     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
parameters  The parameters passed to the command.
​
B           Start application without creating a new window.
```

---